# Save Outlook appointment to specific folder

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

How do I save a new outlook appointment to the same folder as another appointment, for which I have the EntryID? The folder should be the same one that the "currentitem" appointment is saved to. I think I should then use the "item.move" function to set the folder, but I can't get it to work.

```
EntryID = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 23)
Set myolApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set NS = myolApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
NS.Logon
Set CurrentItem = NS.GetItemFromID(EntryID)
Dim MyAppt As Outlook.AppointmentItem
Set MyAppt = Outlook.Application.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
With MyAppt
    .Move (NS.Folders(CurrentItem)) 'THIS IS WHERE I AM STUCK
    .Start = CurrentItem.Start
    .End = CurrentItem.End
    .AllDayEvent = False
    .Display
End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, create the item in the destination folder to begin with using `MAPIFolder.Items.Add` instead of `CreateItem` / `Move`.
If you need to figure out the parent folder of another item, cast `MailItem.Parent` property to `MAPIFolder`.

Secondly (it won't matter if you use `MAPIFolder.Items.Add`) - `Move` is a function that returns the newly created item, and the original item from that moment on must not be touched. Your code ignores the new item and keeps setting the properties on the old (moved) item.

Comment: The problem is I still don't know what folder I am saving to, because it should be the same one as the CurrentItem is in. If I could reference that folder, then I could easily save a new item to that location. How do I find that folder? I have edited my question to clarify that. Apologies that it was not clear.

Comment: Sorry this is still not making sense to me. MAPIFolder is evidently a variable, but set as what?

Comment: MAPIFolder is the object type - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2003/aa210948(v%3Doffice.11)

Comment: In your case, the code should be Set MyAppt = CurrentItem.Parent.Items.Add

Comment: Oh, ok that makes sense to me now. It works great, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`CurrentItem` is already set as the folder to which you are moving the folder. If it were the identifying string, not the folder, your code would be correct. However, because it's the folder, you just need to `.Move CurrentItem`.

Comment: CurrentItem is not a folder, but an outlook appointment item. I would like to save the new appointment item to the same location. I have edited my question to clarify that. Apologies that it was not clear.